# Create LaTeX document in MATLAB (MATLAB Plugin?)

Tags: latex, matlab

Can't use LaTeX software on work computer but I have Matlab and can get plugins for it. I know Matlab is powerful. Has anyone written a plugin to use it to create LaTeX documents?

On my company computers we are very restricted on what software we are able to install. LaTeX software is not on the "approved" list and I can't get them to change that. I do have Matlab though... So I thought maybe there is a workaround.

I'd like to know if anyone has a decent solution and if not, where should I start to get one. Note, I'm not a code developer so I may not have the time to invest to create this thing myself. Thoughts?

Also: I cannot use a web-based service since I am working with proprietary data.